# Multiple AJAX requests with React Redux

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, reactjs, redux

I want to make requests to two different APIs. I then need to organize that data. I'm using redux-promise.

Currently, I have a function, calls two other functions that do the AJAX request:

```
export function fetchEstimates(input) {
  let firstRequest = fetchFirstRequest(input);
  let secondRequest = fetchFirstRequest(input);

  return {
    type: FETCH_DATA,
    payload: {
      firstRequest: firstRequest
      secondRequest: secondRequest
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, by putting both requests in an object, I can't seem to access the results.

```
export default function(state = [], action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_DATA:
      // console.log(action.firstRequest);
      // console.log(action.secondRequest);
      return result;
  }
  return state;
}
```

As I toggle the object in dev tools, I come to this:

```
[[PromiseStatus]]:"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]:Object
```

I can continue to toggle the options, but I can't seem to access them in my code.

If in my payload, I just return this

```
payload: firstRequest
```

I don't have issues. But of course, I need both requests. Any ideas. What is a good approach to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [source for redux-promise](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise/blob/master/src/index.js), you'll see that it assumes you've provided a promise as the "payload" field in your action.  You're instead providing an object with two promises as sub-fields under "payload".  I'm assuming that you're really interested in having both promises resolve, and then passing both results to the reducer.  You'd want to use `Promise.all` to create a new promise that receives the results of both original promises as an argument, then use that promise as your payload.  The reducer would then receive something like: `{type : "DATA_RECEIVED", payload : [response1, response2]}`.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of middleware to deal with `Promise`s (like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)), and wrap the promises in `Promise.all` to wait until they're both resolved. Let me know if you need a code example.

Comment: Yeah, could I see a code example? Is it necessary to do this with redux-thunk? I don't mind using thunks in my code, I'm just curious if redux-promise can't handle this due to some limitation.